# Why doesn't “\vphantom” work in section titles?

Tags: math-mode, sectioning

For reasons of my own (so please don't advise me to simply not do that, I considered that already) I want to have this expression in the title of a section

```
\section{$\left< a \vphantom{L} \right| \left. b\vphantom{L} \right>$}
```

but this gives me

```
! Incomplete \iffalse;
```

Any idea why that happens? And maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command `\vphantom` is fragile. You need to protect it:

```
\section{$\left< a \protect\vphantom{L} \right| \left. b\protect\vphantom{L} \right>$}
```

However, there's a better way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{$\left< a \protect\vphantom{L} \right| \left. b\protect\vphantom{L} \right>$}

\section{$\langle a \mid b \rangle$}

\section{$\left< a \;\middle|\; b\right>$}

\end{document}
```

The first is your code, the second is what I'd prefer, because `\left` and `\right` are really doing nothing. The third uses `\middle`. As you notice, the first has the spacing wrong.

[image]